# How can I mock SpringApplication.run with mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have tried to mock this line

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
```

that is in my main class. However,every attempt I made ended up running the application, connecting to the database, etc. Is there a simple way to mock this execution so I can mock test the rest of my class?
The need for this is that I need to increase the coverage of my class because there is the following logic after

```
Integer processingType = ApplicationUtils.validateParameters(args);

        Controller controller = applicationContext.getBean(Controller.class);

        if (processingType == 1) {
            log.info("executing parameter 1");
            controller.loadFile();
        }
        if (processingType == 2) {
            log.info("executing parameter 2");
            controller.updateByDate();
        }
```

I am using SpringBoot 2.7.1, Mockito 4.5.1 and  Junit-jupter 5.8.2

Thats is one of my many tries

```
    @SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Mock
    private ApplicationUtils utils;

    @Mock
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Mock
    private Controller controller;

    @Mock
    private SpringApplication springApplication;

    @Mock
    private Environment env;

    @InjectMocks
    private Application app;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }


    @Test
    void applicationTestErroParametro3() throws Exception {
        String[] args = {"asd","asd","8"};
        int statusCode = catchSystemExit(() -> {
            app.main(args);
            verify(utils, atLeast(1)).validateParameters(args);
            doThrow(new BusinessException("invalid argmuents")).when(utils).validateParameters(args);
        });
        assertEquals(99, statusCode);
    }
    @Test
    void applicationTestParameter1() throws Exception {
        String[] args = {"1","1","1"};
        when(springApplication.run()).thenReturn(applicationContext);
        when(context.getEnvironment()).thenReturn(env);
        int statusCode = catchSystemExit(() -> {
            doNothing().when(controller).loadFile();
            app.main(args);
            verify(utils, atLeast(1)).validateParameters(args);
        });
        assertEquals(1, statusCode);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Don't try to just start the app in your test. Use something like `@SpringBootTest` instead. More details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing) (and a ton of other Google-able articles)

Comment: @Jorn I have edited the question with one of my attempts, can you please check if that's what you mentioned?